# Can I take a part of a map and test the key I use?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, filter, java-stream

I want to create a Filtered TreeMap from another TreeMap using keys in a method parameter but also I want to test those values ?

I tried this :

```java
    public TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> getInfoById(int... ids) {
        try (IntStream stream = Arrays.stream(ids)) {
            return stream.boxed().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            i -> i,
                            info::get, //Info is a TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>
                            (i1, i2) -> {
                                throw new IllegalStateException("Two keys are similar");
                            },
                            TreeMap::new
                    )
            );
        }
    }
```

but I want to be sure that in `ids` there will not be a number over 807 (because there's always 807 key so I don't want someone to look for the 808 key)

what can I add to look if my stream doesn't contains an int over 807

edit: to be more precise I would like to throw an exception if one of the ids is over 807

Comment: you mean, you only need `ids` <808 with values in result `Map` ?

Comment: `stream.filter(i -> i < 808).boxed()...`?

Comment: is it possible to throw an exception if one the ids is > 807

Comment: `if (Instream.of(ids).anyMatch(id -> id > 807)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("..."); }` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.IntPredicate-

Answer (score 0):

The answers as been given in comment but:
if I wanted to just filter without giving a throwback on it I should use

```java
stream.filter(i -> i < 808).boxed()...
```

but I wanted to throw an error if that happened so I used

```java
if (Instream.of(ids).anyMatch(id -> id > 807)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("..."); }
```